# ACF / PHP Repeater count

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, logical-operators, advanced-custom-fields

I have a repeater using Advanced Custom fields, which when a count reaches a total (of 3) based on an iterative count, I would like to output a div, then reset the counter.

Here's the code, at the moment it's not outputting as it should and I don't know enough about math to get it to work.

Appreciate your assistance :-)

```
      <?php if(have_rows('flexible_row')) : ?>
  <div class="row">
    <?php if(empty($count)){ $count=1;} while(have_rows('flexible_row')) : the_row(); ?>
        <?php if(get_sub_field('column_width') == "One column") { $count = $count+1; ?>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <?php the_sub_field('title');?>
            <?php the_sub_field('content');?>
            Count is <?php echo $count; ?>
            <hr/>
          </div>
        <?php } if(get_sub_field('column_width') == "Two columns") { $count = $count+2; ?>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <?php the_sub_field('title');?>
            <?php the_sub_field('content');?>
            Count is <?php echo $counter; ?>
            <hr/>
          </div>
        <?php } else { $count = $count+3; ?>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <?php the_sub_field('title');?>
            <?php the_sub_field('content');?>
            Count is <?php echo $counter; ?>
            <hr/>
          </div>
      <?php } if ($count == 3) {  ?></div><div class="row"><?php $count = 0; } ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Problem 1 solved: I was using `echo $counter` instead of `echo $count`, this has resolved the first issue problem!

Answer (score 0):

Think I'd got my logic mixed up a bit — I wasn't using the `else` clauses correctly. Here's the final working code in case anyone stumbles across this in the future:

```
      <?php if(have_rows('flexible_row')) : ?>
  <div class="row">
    <?php if(empty($count)){ $count=0;} while(have_rows('flexible_row')) : the_row(); ?>
        <?php if(get_sub_field('column_width') == "One Column") { $count = $count+1; ?>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <?php the_sub_field('title');?>
            <?php the_sub_field('content');?>
          </div>
        <?php } elseif(get_sub_field('column_width') == "Two Columns") { $count = $count+2; ?>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <?php the_sub_field('title');?>
            <?php the_sub_field('content');?>
          </div>
        <?php } else { $count = $count+3; ?>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <?php the_sub_field('title');?>
            <?php the_sub_field('content');?>
          </div>
      <?php } if ($count == 3) {  ?></div><div class="row"><?php $count = 0; } ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div>
```

You could of course use `switch` statements too..